# Printing all paths in a directed graph using lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, graph, directed-graph

I will start this off by saying that I am relatively new to python so forgive me if the answer is obvious. I made a class for a directed graph and I need to add a method to print all of the non-cyclical paths from a starting vertex to an ending vertex. I have tried a few times, but the way I am trying to do it has me a little bit confused.

Here is my class:

```
import string

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertexlist = []
        self.edgelist = []
        self.numedges = 0
        self.numvertices = 0

    def add_vertex(self, name):
        check = False
        for item in self.vertexlist:
            if name == item:
                check = True
                break

        if check is False:
            self.vertexlist.append(name)
            self.numvertices = self.numvertices + 1
        else:
            print "A vertex with that name already exists."

    def add_edge(self, start, end):
        if start not in self.vertexlist:
            self.vertexlist.append(start)
            self.numvertices += 1

        if end not in self.vertexlist:
            self.vertexlist.append(end)
            self.numvertices += 1

        tempedge = [start, end]

        self.edgelist.append(tempedge)
        self.numedges += 1

    def remove_vertex(self, name):
        if name in slef.vertexlist:
            self.vertexlist.remove(name)
            self.numvertices = self.numvertices - 1
        else:
            pass

    def remove_edge(self, start, end):
        for item in self.edgelist:
            if item[0] is start and item[1] is end:
                self.edgelist.remove(item)
                self.numedges = self.numedges - 1

    def vertices(self):
        return self.vertexlist

    def print_edges(self):
        for x in self.edgelist:
            print x[0] + " -> " + x[1]

    def is_connected(self, start, end):
        for item in self.edgelist:
            if item[0] is start and item[1] is end:
                return True;

        return False

    def pathFinder(self, begin, fin, p = None): # print_paths helper function
        if p is None:
            p = []

        p = p + [begin]

        if begin == fin:
            return [p]

        pathing = []
        for item in self.edgelist:
            if item[0] not in p:
                newpath = self.pathFinder(item[0], fin, p)

                for i in newpath:
                    pathing.append(i)

        return pathing

    def print_paths(self, start, end):
        temp = self.pathFinder(start, end)

        print temp
```

The last two functions are the ones that I am having trouble with (`print_paths` and `pathFinder`). The goal is to have `pathFinder` return a list of lists, where each inner list is a path sequence.

For example, if A -> B, A -> C, B -> D, C -> D

then there are two paths from A to D and pathFinder should return:
`[ ['A','B','D'] , ['A','C','D'] ]`

I have seen some other implementations/questions about a similar goal, but I haven't seen anything that uses lists as the underlying data structure like I am trying to. The other ways might be better, but I would like to continue the way I have it now if that is possible.

Edit - adding code to test the class below:

```
from graph import Graph

g = Graph()
g.add_vertex('A')
g.add_vertex('A')
g.add_vertex('B')
g.add_vertex('C')

print "\nVertices:", g.vertices()

g.add_edge('A', 'B')
g.add_edge('B', 'C')
g.add_edge('C', 'D')
g.add_edge('C', 'B')
g.add_edge('B', 'D')
g.add_edge('D', 'A')

print"\nEdges:"
g.print_edges()

print "\nA->B?", g.is_connected('A', 'B')
print "B->A?", g.is_connected('B', 'A')
print "C->D?", g.is_connected('C', 'D')

print "\nAll non-cyclical paths from A to D:"
g.print_paths('A', 'D')
```

Current Output:

```
A vertex with name 'A' already exists.

Vertices: ['A', 'B', 'C']

Edges:
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
C -> B
B -> D
D -> A

A->B? True
B->A? False
C->D? True

Paths from A to D:
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 
'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], 
['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 
'D'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'D']]
```

It gives 13 possible paths, but really only 2 exist

Comment: So, have you written it and can't understand why it works? Or do you need t write it? This part isn't clear.

Comment: I wrote it, but it does not work as intended and I cannot seem to figure out why

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but I see two problems with `pathFinder()`. First is minor: the first argument to classes methods should, by convention, be named `self`. Second is the `p = []` in the declaration. You shouldn't give arguments mutable default values because they will retain their  value from any previous call to the method if they're used more than once. A common workaround is to use  `p = None` and  then explicitly check for that at the beginning of the method: i.e. `if p is None: p = []`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear. My fault. The question is how can I print all the possible paths (non - cyclical) from vertex A to vertex B. Right now the function prints paths that do not actually exist. Also, thank you martineau I'll fix those two things

Comment: @AustinJames Sorry, but can you also post the code you use to initialise the graph? Thanks.

Comment: I definitely can, but I don't post here often so is there a correct way of doing that or just edit the original post?

Comment: Edit your question to include it.

Comment: @Coldspeed Alright I have included it

Comment: @AustinJames You're adding A twice and not adding D at all?

Comment: @austin could you also include the output you're getting?

Comment: @Coldspeed -  yes it is an error check. The add_vertex() function checks if there is already an existing vertex with that name. The add_edge() function will create a new vertex if it is given a starting or ending point that does not already exist. If that makes sense at all

Comment: @AustinJames While that is purely a design aspect, it makes your graph less fault tolerant, because that way people can specify faulty edges and your system will blindly cater to those requests.

Comment: @AustinJames yeah but am i correct in that you've only added two vertices -- 'a' and 'c'? and then you're trying to add edges between 'a', 'c' and non-existent vertices 'b' and 'd'?

Comment: @Coldspeed if you add an edge between non existent vertices it creates those vertices, also I added my output like you asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graph.py`

```
import string
import copy

class Graph(object):
    ...
    def print_paths(self, start, end):
    # Initialise a dict mapping nodes to whether they've been 
    # visited or not. Each path must maintain state about which 
    # nodes have been visited, and one path must not clash with 
    # another.
        visited = {v : False for v in self.vertexlist} 
        temp = self.pathFinder(start, end, visited)
        print temp

    def pathFinder(self, begin, fin, visited, p=None):
        # Mark this node as visited.
        visited[begin] = True 
        if p is None:
            p = []

        p = p + [begin]
        # Stopping condition - Success.
        if begin == fin: 
            return [p]

        pathlist = []
        # Since you're using a list to store edges, 
        # this makes things a little messy.
        #  We need to check for a couple of things.
        for item in self.edgelist: 
            # First, make sure that we are following a valid path
            # and second, make sure the end of this edge has not 
            # already been visited. If not, we're ready to jump in
            if begin == item[0] and not visited[item[1]]: 
                # The next recursive call will take a 
                # fresh copy of visited and attempt to repeat 
                # the process until it has found the end.
                newpath = self.pathFinder(item[1], fin, copy.copy(visited), p)     
                pathlist.extend(newpath)

        return pathlist # Stopping condition - Failure.
```

**Case 1**

```
A -> B
A -> C
B -> D
C -> D
```

```
All non-cyclical paths from A to D:
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D']]
```

**Case 2**

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
C -> B
B -> D
D -> A
```

```
All non-cyclical paths from A to D:
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
```

Explanation in comments.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Coldspeed. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Austin, let me know if I can clarify anything. I understand that the reasoning behind why it works and why it wasn't working before may not be obvious at first glance.

Comment: No your comments made enough sense. If anything pops up as I continue though I will just leave another comment. Thanks again.